# Passing multiple values as query string is good or bad practice in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my page I ve to pass multiple values to controller.

My URL looks something like : 
http://blah/Search/Page/?type=new&keywords=blahblah&sortType=Date

Is Passing multiple values as query string good practice in MVC ? or We can have slash separated URL, by using introducing custom routing?

NB: Lets consider all the values in my query string, are not secure / sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't consider it a bad practice, as long as it's not senstive data. It just depends if you want to write a custom route in your global.asax to handle it or not. The custom routes provide a cleaner url forsure. Also, for more savy users if they understand the concept on your site, it's more intuitive.

So consider this:

```
http://baseballcards/topps/1980      // search for baseball cards made by topps in the 1980s
http://recipes/deserts/pies         // search for a desert recipe that are pies  
http://code/csharpe/linq             // search for csharp code that has linq examples
```

In these examples we can almost read the url like a sentence, making it more intuitive, giving a user the ability to plug and play. It clearly denotes the query almost like a breadcrumb, indicating exactly what the context will be. I personally like this. But either way is a good approach.

To extend with more parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchRecipes",                                              
            "Search/Recipes/{category}/{type}",                           
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Recipes", category = "all" , type = ""}  
 );
```

Some examples:

```
Search/Recipes/Deserts/Pie
Search/Recipes/Dinner/Beef
Search/Recipes/Lunch/Salads
```

Comment: I do understand the readability of the above approach, but can we still extend it further? Like the case I ve demonstrated above where only one parameter is not enough... For example I want to specify the drink type too (say hot or cold drink) to  http://recipies/deserts/pies

Comment: You can have as many parameters as you need. You just need to define this in your custom route in global.asax. I am updating my answer...

Comment: Yes, We can add that extra routing in Global.asax & when we type the URL like ../Search/Recipes/Deserts/Pie, we can get redirected to that page. But how to generate that URL through our code? When we try to add a route value in Url.Action, it comes as a query string. :(

Comment: For example Url.Action( "Recipes" , "Search" , new { type = item.type} ) would give me link that looks like : Search/Recipes?type=Deserts, but I want to generate url like Search/Recipes/Deserts/Pie. Please let me know how we can achieve the same?

Comment: What does your route look like in global.asax. Show me your actual `Url.Action` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Select later (query string in route values) in case,

1. If you are concerned about header length.( By default get parameters are part of headers, and web server accept 1024 byte header length by default in IIS7).
2. Hide logical implementation of your code.
3. Url looks good and easier to remember.

Otherwise Both the approaches work equally.

Answer (score 0):

I think passing search parameters in the query string is the way you should go, especially if all your parameters are optional. It also enables you to use normal `method="get"` forms without hassle.

I don't think "security/personal data" has anything to do with this since the query string is a part of the URL just like the path is.

Answer (score 0):

IMO I think this is absolutely fine. I think it is actually preferable to use querystrings in MVC when the path represents the function and the querystring parameters represent the filters, e.g. as in a search.

However, I wouldn't use querystring parameters for data that represent information about the content retrieved. So I would include the year and month of an article in the path but not the page number if returning more than one page of articles for the year and month.